# How do I remove the first n lines from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
One\n
Two\n
Three\n
Four\n
```

remove_lines(2) would remove the first two lines, leaving the string:

```
Three\n
Four\n
```

Comment: Did some benchmarking: DigitalRoss' solution isn't only the most elegant but also the fastest, NawaMan's version is about 30% slower, my own one is slower by a factor of 2 and Overdose's method is slower by a factor of 3.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### s.to_a[2..-1].join

```
>> s = "One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\n"
=> "One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\n"
>> s.to_a[2..-1].join
=> "Three\nFour\n"
```

Comment: This removes characters from the `String` - not lines.

Comment: Damn. This is even better than my attempt. ;)
Use `s.to_a[i..-1].join` to get the resulting `String` again.

Comment: heh, I've often been frustrated in code-golf by `.to_a` doing the line break thing instead of chars like I want. FINALLY, I get a chance to use it! :-)

Comment: Note: This will not work in Ruby 1.9, in which you'd need to do s.lines.to_a.  See http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/getting_code_ready_for_ruby_19 for more.

Comment: *Note:* the current solution addresses all of the comments and objections.

Comment: `s.lines[2..-1].join` is now the elegant one

Answer (score 7):

```
s = "One\nTwo\nThree\nFour"

lines = s.lines
> ["One\n", "Two\n", "Three\n", "Four"]

remaining_lines = lines[2..-1]
> ["Three\n", "Four"]

remaining_lines.join
> "Three\nFour"
```

- `String#lines` converts the string into an array of lines (retaining the new line character at the end of each string)
- `[2..-1]` specifies the range of lines to return, in this case the third through the last
- `Array#join` concatenates the lines back together, without any space (but since the lines still contain the new line character, we don't need a separator)

In one line:

```
s.lines[2..-1].join
```

Comment: I like this better than the top answer, because the intent of `.lines` is sooo much more obvious and readable than `.to_a`

Answer (score 5):

```
class String

  def remove_lines(i)
    split("\n")[i..-1].join("\n")
  end

end
```

Calling `"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\n".remove_lines(2)` would result in `"Three\nFour"`. If you need the trailing `"\n"` you need to extend this method accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't the method keep empty lines as-is?

Answer (score 3):

I had a situation where I needed to support multiple platform EOLN (both \r and \n), and had success with the following:

```
split(/\r\n|\r|\n/, 2).last
```

Or the equivalent `remove_lines`:

```
def remove_lines(number_of_lines=1)
  split(/\r\n|\r|\n/, number_of_lines+1).last
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure regexp one-liner. Hypothetically it should be even faster than the elegant solution provided by @DigitalRoss:

```
n = 4 # number of lines
str.gsub(/\A(.*\n){#{n}}/,'')
```

If you know in advance how many line you want to cut (4 here):

```
str.gsub(/\A(.*\n){4}/,'')
```

And if you want to cut only one line:

```
str.gsub(/\A.*\n/,'')
```

In order to cut n lines from the tail:

```
gsub(/(\n.*){#{n}}\Z/,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem will remove the first two lines using regular expression.

```
Text = "One\nTwo\nThree\nFour"
Text = Text.gsub /^(?:[^\n]*\n){2}/, ''
# -----------------------------------^^  (2) Replace with nothing
# ----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       (1) Detect first 2 lines
puts Text
```

**EDIT:** I've just saw that the question is also about '`n`' lines not just two lines.

So here is my new answer.

```
Lines_Removed = 2
Original_Text = "One\nTwo\nThree\nFour"
Result___Text = (Original_Text.gsub(Regexp.new("([^\n]*\n){%s}" % Lines_Removed), ''))
#                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^
# - (1) Detect first  lines -----++++++++++++++                    ||
# - (2) Replace with nothing -----------------------------------------------------++

puts Result___Text # Returns "Three\nFour"
```

Comment: thanks for trying to do it without breaking to array and re-assembling (tho didnt exactly work for me)

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_lines(str, n)
  res = ""
  arr = str.split("\n")[n..(str.size-n)]
  arr.each { |i| res.concat(i + "\n")  }
  return res
end

a = "1\n2\n3\n4\n"
b = remove_lines(a, 2)
print b
```